# Invalidate PushButton control until asynchronous custom action completes MSI

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, orca

In my installer, I have an asynchronous dll custom action that executes before the welcome screen appears and gathers some necessary information for the installer to work. Before I had it set as synchronous, but what happens is there is no welcome screen for about 15 seconds or more (depending on computer). So I changed it to asynchronous which allows the welcome screen to appear, which is what I want.

But now I want the Next button to be invalid until the CA returns ERROR_SUCCESS.

Can I do this by editing the MSI with Orca? That would be my preference. Otherwise, can I do this from within another custom action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a modeless dialog to appear while your custom action runs. For example, in WiX, the PrepareDlg is shown while the AppSearch standard action processes machine searches.

Comment: So all I need to do is add the modeless Dialog and put that before the custom action I want to run in the InstallUIExecute table? I saw that WiX does that, but I couldn't figure out how it all worked.

Comment: Yes, see "Dialog Style Bits" in the MSI SDK. The dialog stays up until another dialog replaces it.

Comment: Perfect! The only thing I didn't understand was that the dialog automatically disappeared when a new one popped up. Thanks!